# This pipe program is not compiling

Tags: c, pipe

I am learning OS course.
We were taught pipes and this program is not getting compiled in GCC 4.4.7. When we change `main` to `int main`, it compiles fine. What is the reason?

Command line:   `gcc pipedemo.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

main()
{
        char source[]="pipe_program";
        char dest[BUFFER_SIZE];
        char datas[BUFFER_SIZE];
        char datar[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int fd1[2],fd2[2];
        pid_t pid;
        if(pipe(fd1)==-1)
        {
                fprintf(stderr,"Pipe creation failed\n");
                exit(0);
        }

       if(pipe(fd2)==-1)
       {
           //...
       }
       //...
 }
```

Comment: Are there any reason you or your friend want to use non-standard syntax of function definition?

Comment: The reason may be `-Werror` option or something. Would you mind disclosing the command line option?

Comment: @MikeCAT I have no reason but by default the return type is int so we wrote that. But I want to know what is the error, Not intrested in compilation

Comment: @MikeCAT sure edited

Comment: "is not getting compiled " - you know this *how*? What is the reported error message from the failed compile attempt ? it belongs, verbatim, in your question.

Comment: Note that the style of defining `main()` without an explicit return type of `int` was made obsolete (invalid) by the C99 standard.  You should not be coding to the archaic C89/C90 standard which did allow the notation without an explicit return type.  You should be adhering to C11, using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11` (or substituting `-std=gnu11` if you prefer).  And your code should compile cleanly under those options.

Answer (score 2):

The standard (ISO/IEC 9899-2011) says about `main`:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation
>   declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>     parameters:
>
> ```
>       int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>    used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>       int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;

So that ends it all?
No, not that easy. At the end of the quote is a small semicolon and what follows is this little, seemingly innocent part

> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Than there is the difference between "hosted" (section 5.1.2.2 within an OS and its rules) and "freestanding" (in section 5.1.2.1. For example on a small PIC or similar, barely any rules at all and the rest is implementation defined)

The syntax of a function definition is defined in section 6.9.1 where it reads in item 1

> The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified by the declarator portion of the function definition.

Further detailed in item 2

> The return type of a function shall be void or a complete object type other than array type.

So any function definition (including `main`) must have a return type specified.

But see the rules for the "freestanding environment" above or better, the lack of them.

Comment: For a full discussion, see [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)